# Cambiar el valor 'name' de un 'select' con un JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, formularios

Tengo un formulario en el cual a través de un radiobutton elijo una lista desplegable u otra, cuyo valor quiero pasarlo a través del name a un modelo de mi aplicación para que lo añada a la base de datos, tal que:

FORMULARIO:

```
<label for="size" class="col-md-4 control-label">Tamaño</label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="radio" id="numero" value="numero">Numero<br>
     <select class="form-control hidden" name="size" id="lista_numero">
          <option value="">--Escoja el tamaño--</option>
          <option value="1">nº 1</option>
          <option value="2">nº 2</option>
          <option value="3">nº 3</option>
     </select>
     <input type="radio" id="simple" value="simple">Valor simple<br>
        <select class="form-control hidden" name="size" id="lista_simple">
            <option value="">--Escoja el tamaño--</option>
            <option value="3">3 cm</option>
            <option value="5">5 cm</option>
            <option value="10">10 cm</option>
            <option value="20">20 cm</option>
            <option value="30">30 cm</option>
         </select>
      <input type="radio" id="compuesto" value="compuesto">Valor compuesto<br>
         <select class="form-control hidden" name="size" id="lista_compuesto1">
             <option value="">--Escoja el ancho--</option>
             <option value="5">5 cm</option>
             <option value="10">10 cm</option>
             <option value="15">15 cm</option>
             <option value="20">20 cm</option>
             <option value="30">30 cm</option>
             <option value="50">50 cm</option>
             <option value="60">60 cm</option>
         </select>
         <select class="form-control hidden" name="size" id="lista_compuesto2">
             <option value="">--Escoja el alto--</option>
             <option value="0,25">0.25 cm</option>
             <option value="0,5" select="selected">0.5 cm</option>
             <option value="1">1 cm</option>
             <option value="2">2 cm</option>
             <option value="5">5 cm</option>
             <option value="25">25 cm</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Siendo JQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#numero').click(function(){
       $('#lista_numero').removeClass("hidden");
       $('#lista_simple').addClass("hidden");
       $('#lista_compuesto1').addClass("hidden");
       $('#lista_compuesto2').addClass("hidden");
    });
    $('#simple').click(function(){
        $('#lista_numero').addClass("hidden");
        $('#lista_simple').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#lista_compuesto1').addClass("hidden");
        $('#lista_compuesto2').addClass("hidden");
    });
    $('#compuesto').click(function(){
        $('#lista_numero').addClass("hidden");
        $('#lista_simple').addClass("hidden");
        $('#lista_compuesto1').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#lista_compuesto2').removeClass("hidden");
    })
</script>
```

Para que me ponga en oculto el resto de listas desplegables si su radiobutton no está seleccionado.
Como en los tres select de las listas desplegables tengo el mismo atributo name="size", cuando mando el formulario la variable 'size' = NULL, ya que existen tres variables con valor y solo seleccionado una(que es el valor real que quiero pasarle a la variable)
Como hago a través de JQuery que solo tenga el atributo name='size' el select que tengo seleccionado???
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

por empezar le colocamos el mismo atributo name a los radio buttons para seleccionar uno solo a la vez.

```
<label for="size" class="col-md-4 control-label">Tamaño</label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="radio" id="numero" value="numero" name="tipovalor">Numero<br>
     <select class="form-control hidden" name="size" id="lista_numero">
          <option value="">--Escoja el tamaño--</option>
          <option value="1">nº 1</option>
          <option value="2">nº 2</option>
          <option value="3">nº 3</option>
     </select><br>
     <input type="radio" id="simple" value="simple" name="tipovalor">Valor simple<br>
        <select class="form-control hidden" name="size" id="lista_simple">
            <option value="">--Escoja el tamaño--</option>
            <option value="3">3 cm</option>
            <option value="5">5 cm</option>
            <option value="10">10 cm</option>
            <option value="20">20 cm</option>
            <option value="30">30 cm</option>
         </select><br>
      <input type="radio" id="compuesto" value="compuesto" name="tipovalor">Valor compuesto<br>
         <select class="form-control hidden" name="size" id="lista_compuesto1">
             <option value="">--Escoja el ancho--</option>
             <option value="5">5 cm</option>
             <option value="10">10 cm</option>
             <option value="15">15 cm</option>
             <option value="20">20 cm</option>
             <option value="30">30 cm</option>
             <option value="50">50 cm</option>
             <option value="60">60 cm</option>
         </select><br>
         <select class="form-control hidden" name="size" id="lista_compuesto2">
             <option value="">--Escoja el alto--</option>
             <option value="0.25">0.25 cm</option>
             <option value="0.5" select="selected">0.5 cm</option>
             <option value="1">1 cm</option>
             <option value="2">2 cm</option>
             <option value="5">5 cm</option>
             <option value="25">25 cm</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```

También cambiamos los values "0,25" y "0,5" por 0.25 y 0.5 respectivamente, asumo que si los vas a usar para hacer operaciones luego o almacenar, es mejor usar directamente el formato decimal que convertir de formato europeo para operar luego.

Luego, donde tengas tu código de jQuery podrías hacer:

```
if ($("input[name='tipovalor']:checked").val() === "numero") {
  // Seleccionó número, asi que
  // Tendrás el valor seleccionado en $("#lista_numero" ).val();
}
if ($("input[name='tipovalor']:checked").val() === "simple") {
  // Seleccionó valor simple, asi que
  // Tendrás el valor seleccionado en $("#lista_simple" ).val();
}
if ($("input[name='tipovalor']:checked").val() === "compuesto") {
  // Seleccionó valor compuesto, asi que
  // Tendrás el primer valor seleccionado en $("#lista_compuesto1" ).val();
  // Tendrás el segundo valor seleccionado en $("#lista_compuesto2" ).val();
}
```

Es solo una idea, desconozco que se hace con esos datos luego, pero la forma más sencilla que se me ocurre es esa.

Comment: Gracias Marcelo !!!!

Comment: Al final lo he solucionado con un switch/case en el controlador del modelo de la base de datos:
        switch($request['size']) {
            case 'numero':  $size = $request['size_numero'];
                            break;
            case 'simple' : $size = $request['size_simple'];
                            break;
            case 'compuesto' : $size = $request['size_compuesto_ancho'] . "x" . $request['size_compuesto_alto'];
                            break;
        }

Comment: Que hagas ese control en el backend no significa que no puedas implementar ambos, las soluciones de frontend NUNCA deben ser consideradas como confiables y siempre deben validarse en los servicios, middlewares, o controladores, depende tu estilo.

Comment: Realmente lo que estoy haciendo es el backend de la aplicacion con Laravel, la parte del frontend la estoy trabajando con ionic+angular